# How to path to a folder in powershell 2.0 that has '[]' in the folder name

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

Im trying to delete folders from a path that has these characters inside the folder `name []` like this

`c:\blah\blah\[_EFI_HotFolder_]\[MoveFolder]`.

I'm very new to PS i have tried many things with no success and cant seem to find any topics on this either.

`PS 2.0`

Comment: `help Get-ChildItem -full` and read (pay particular attention to the `-LiteralPath` parameter).

Comment: Thank you so much that makes alot of sense.. You literally saved me hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -LiteralPath to specify the path check help Get-ChildItem -full as Bill suggested